# How to use angular 2 components written in typescript inside a dart project

Tags: typescript, angular, dart, angular2-components

I'm using dart to develop an angular 2 project.
I've seen some interesting component libraries written in typescript that I would like to use inside my app.
Is it possible? If yes, how?
I googled a lot but I couldn't find any hint...

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do that.

You would need to port the elements source to Dart. The [ts2dart](https://github.com/angular/ts2dart) tool might help, but if the TypeScript code is not built with `ts2dart` in mind, then it will only be able to translate parts of the code.

You might argue that Polymer.js elements can be used in Polymer.dart, but Polymer.dart itself is just a wrapper for Polymer.js and Polymer elements are wrapped in a similar way.
Because Dart Angular2 is entirely Dart code this approach is not available.

Angular also requires build tools to be applied to the components code and these build tools are different for TS and Dart.

Dart and JS Polymer elements can be use with Dart Angular2 though.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's a pity. It would be interesting to have that possibility, as it seems that most of the development for angular2 will be done in TS. Last chance: porting the TS sources to JS and than using them with package:js is an option or you would discourage such a job?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, at least not with an reasonable amount of work. It's necessary to build the whole Angular2 application at once. There is no way to build single components and then use the output together. There are no tools to build a partly Dart and partly JS application at once. What you could do is to run two Angular2 applications on one page where one is Angular2.js and the other Angular2.dart and communication using dart-js-interop.